# Is it possible to turn off JavaScript for some tests using Codeception?

Tags: laravel, selenium-webdriver, codeception, acceptance-testing

We have client-side validation and server-side validation as a back up in this Laravel application, and we want to test both, but I can't figure out if that's possible.  Is it possible to turn off JavaScript for a single run of the tests, then run them again with it on using Codeception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with PhpBrowser or Laravel5 module.
They can't execute Javascript, so only server side validation is possible.

You will have to create a separate test suite (or use functional if you aren't using it yet) for these tests, because you can have only one of WebDriver, PhpBrowser and Laravel5 modules enabled at a time.